# Any sources for learning assembly programming in Windows?

Tags: assembly

I would like to learn Assembly Programming for Windows. But I am having some problems to found material for learning. All the material I see don't give enough code to program (they show just snippets), are too old, or are just theory.

Comment: have you checked your local public library? There have been many books published over the years.

Comment: As I said before, I checked it but most of the material I find is too theoretical or don't show enough code. I want something that gives full example of source code.

Comment: You’ll have to be more specific about what you want and what you have already found. Do you already know basic/DOS Assembly? Do you want to write a Windows console program in assembler? Do you want to write a GUI program? Have you tried the HelloWin.asm examples that print “Hello World” in a plain windows? Do you have WINDOWS.INC and its ilk? Googling `windows assembler` returns a pretty good [PDF](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigwin/old/workshops/winasmtut.pdf) with good decent examples. [The Art of Assembly](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/) includes Windows programming as well.

Comment: I may be either a console or GUI. I want to learn windows assembly so I could learn disassembly and reverse engineering for Windows to solve problems with executables.

Comment: If he already knows assembler, HLA probably isn't the best choice.

Comment: It’s not Windows assembler that you need to learn; you need to first learn basic Assembler. That is, you need to learn the instruction set, basic commands, working with memory, jumps, and so on. Pretty much any book on assembler (eg in the library) will give you the basics you need to understand assembler. Once you know that, then learning “windows assembly” isn’t much more work; it’s just knowing the message loop and a few other constructs, and mostly, just recognizing the calls to Windows API functions (which you don’t do by eye, the disassembler flags them for you).

Comment: @Mike, the main AoA book includes some actual Windows code (eg hello-world); HLA is a separate module, and from what I can tell, he needs to learn basic asm, so AoA would probably be a good read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a long time, the 'standard' tutorial beginners start with for Windows assembly programming is [Iczelion's tutorial](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/Win32Asm/IczelionTuts/). Also for Windows assembler programming, the best forum (IMO) to get started is probably MASM32. It has a very active community which is very welcoming and helpful to newcomers and beginners. It sort of depends which particular flavour of assembler you want to learn but IMO, for Windows MASM32 has the best userbase (both in terms of community and resources around) for beginners.

You mention you want to learn RCE (reverse code engineering) also. A very common starting place for reversing on Windows is [lena151's tutorials](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.17) which potentially is also a nice start if you already know assembler conceptually from having done Linux assembler programming.

Comment: lzcelion's tutorial was not available now :-(

Comment: @yegle: Try this mirror: http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tutorials.html

Answer (score 5):

Most assembly language programming you would do, especially in a full-OS environment like Windows, will just be snippets anyway (as opposed to a 100% assembly program). The easiest way to get started is to write a C program as a test harness and have it call your assembly language functions.  Here's a simple example:

asm.s:

```
  .text
  .globl _asm_add

_asm_add:
  mov %rdi, %rax
  add %rsi, %rax
  ret
```

example.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int asm_add(int, int);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int a = 12;
  int b = 6;

  int c = asm_add(a, b);

  printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, c);

  return 0;
}
```

Build and run (on my Mac with clang; modify for your compiler on windows):

```
$ clang -o example example.c asm.s
$ ./example 
12 + 6 = 18
```

Comment: @Victor, so then what's the difference?  That same program runs exactly the same on windows as it does on linux or on a mac (well, after exchanging `rdi` & `rsi` for `rcx` & `rdx`, anyway).

Comment: The difference is that different operating systems have different ways to call system services like opening files, output to the screen and so on.

Comment: @Victor, but those are just function calls.  Do you mean you don't want to link against the Windows libraries?

Comment: i want to link against the Windows libraries, but if the function calls are different how do I know how to call them?

Comment: @Victor, you can call the same functions from an assembly program as you can from a C program.  It sounds more like you need to learn about the Win32 API than you do about assembly language.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing to get is the Intel manuals (other manufacturers like AMD will also have their own, but the instructions are very similar):

http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

Those have all the instructions , costs and some guides to programming.